# How to update/merge contacts in CNContact

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cncontact

I am trying to import vcf file in my contacts.When First time I save a contact it imported successfully, no problem.But when I am trying to update that same contact it's doing nothing.What I want? I want if I will update contact then  phone numbers add in exist contact.I am using CNContact.

to save contacts:

```
-(void)saveVCardContacts:(CNContact *)contact{
    NSError * error;


    CNSaveRequest *saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc]init];
    [saveRequest addContact:[contact mutableCopy] toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];
    BOOL success =  [self.store executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:&error];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"import successfully");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);

}
```

to update

```
-(void)updateVCardContacts:(CNContact *)contact{


    NSError *error; 
    CNSaveRequest *saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc]init];
    [saveRequest updateContact:[contact mutableCopy]];
    BOOL success =  [self.store executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:&error];

    if(success)
         NSLog(@"update successfully");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);


}
```

Comment: you want to save a contact or you want to replace the number with existing contact?

Comment: I saved contact, no problem. I want update a contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace your number with only names

```
CNSaveRequest * saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc]init];
    CNContactStore * store = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];

    NSArray*  arrFetchedcontact = nil;
    @try {

        NSError * err = nil;
        NSArray * keytoFetch = @[CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
        NSPredicate * predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsMatchingName:GivenNames];
        arrFetchedcontact = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keytoFetch error:&err];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"description = %@",[exception description]);
    }

    if([arrFetchedcontact count] > 0)
    {

        NSLog(@"ArrFetchedContact %@",arrFetchedcontact);


        CNMutableContact * contactToUpdate = [[arrFetchedcontact objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
        NSMutableArray * arrNumbers = [[contactToUpdate phoneNumbers] mutableCopy];
        [arrNumbers removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        CNLabeledValue * homePhone = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:FieldNumbers]];

        NSLog(@"Print Homephone %@",homePhone);


        [arrNumbers addObject:homePhone];
        [contactToUpdate setPhoneNumbers:arrNumbers];

        [saveRequest updateContact:contactToUpdate];

        @try {

            NSLog(@"Success %d",[store executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:nil]);


        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"description = %@",[exception description]);
        }
    }
```

### Field number is the number you want to replace with given name

### Given name is the name for the person with that number

Comment: what is ReplaceAppleService function

Comment: No you dont need that, its my code for backend, With above code you can make it work.

Comment: If any further queries we can move to discussion room

Comment: then where I will put new dummy number

Comment: Sorry check my recent edit,Field number is the one where you need to change with given name

Comment: Let me know whether you got it or not?